# How do I assert with a regexp that a scalar has only digits but no alphabetic characters?

Tags: perl

I want to match against a variable `$x = 'AA12CB'`. I am using the regexp

```
$x =~ /\b[0-9]+\b/
```

I want to assert that I have only numbers, but not alphabetic characters. This regex is not working.

Comment: why you require **\b**? It matches word boundary, try without **\b**

Answer (score 4):

You need to **anchor** the pattern at the beginning and end of the string to exclude any other characters. This is similar to what you tried with the `\b` boundaries. Read [perlretut](http://p3rl.org/retut) for the meaning of anchoring, it appears a couple of times.

```
use 5.010;
my $x = 'AA12CB';
if ($x =~ /\A [0-9]+ \z/msx) {
    say 'only digits'
} else {
    say 'not only digits'
}
```

Perhaps you rather want [to determine whether a scalar is a number/whole/integer/float](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq4.html#How-do-I-determine-whether-a-scalar-is-a-number-whole-integer-float-).

Comment: This should be one of the strange regex. Modifiers **m & s** are used but no **^/$/.** used. Modifier **x** used, yet it ain't multi-line regex and no comments. Spaces to __accommodate__ for **x modifier** is the strangest of all.

Comment: I follow and also teach good style, see chapter 12 in [PBP](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001735), and also [P-C-P-RE-RLBM](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic::Policy::RegularExpressions::RequireLineBoundaryMatching), [P-C-P-RE-RDMA](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic::Policy::RegularExpressions::RequireDotMatchAnything), [P-C-P-RE-REF](http://p3rl.org/Perl::Critic::Policy::RegularExpressions::RequireExtendedFormatting). I loathe the sort of comments "but any(m,s,x) isn't even necessary here!" That's not the point. **Consistency** is.

Comment: Well the best thing about opinions is that you can always get another. [check this about always using /msx](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=484238)

Comment: That old chestnut again. The point of that article does not apply. I am not modifying an existing regex, I am writing new. It is impossible for me to introduce subtle bugs through a changed meaning when there is no previous regex/meaning.

Answer (score 2):

I think for strings without line-endings, this expression best captures that criteria:

```
$x !~ /\D/
```

It means that at no point does `$x` match a non-digit character. Of course if you still wanted the line endings for an un-`chomp`-ed string, then you have to use a negative character class, like so:

$x !~ /[^\d\n]/

That is `$x` does not match a string that has a character which is not a digit or a newline.

Answer (score 1):

This should also work in Perl.

```
$x = "AA12CB";
unless($x=~m/\D/) {
  print("$x: Just digits\n");
}
else {
  print("$x: Not just digits\n\n");
}

$x = "1223456";
unless($x=~m/\D/) {
  print("$x: Just digits\n");
}
else {
  print("$x: Not just digits\n");
}
```

`\D` is the key here. It matches anything that is NOT a digit. You can easily write this as `if` and `else` rather than `unless` and `else`.

Comment: Please, avoid the use of `unless() { } else {}`

Answer (score 1):

If you're just after a test for numericness, [`Scalar::Util`](https://metacpan.org/module/Scalar%3a%3aUtil)'s `looks_like_number` function should suffice:

```
use Scalar::Util 'looks_like_number';

print   looks_like_number( $x )
      ?   "$x is numeric\n"
      :   "$x is non-numeric\n";
```

I don't think the quirky `'0 but true'` will be encountered in your application...

Comment: If you use this solution, you should hope that `84E19` is not encountered, either.